# Is it possible to make a base that's impenetrable by other players?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

This question stems from a discussion I had with some friends.

- Consider a hypothetical multiplayer vanilla Minecraft server.
- The landscape is random, not premade or prepared in any way.
- All players are playing in survival mode.
- No cheats are allowed.
- The players don't necessarily want to play as allies (they could form alliances, but there will be opposing sides).
- We want to let the players be completely free - i.e. not have to respect any particular rule (like "don't break blocks in other people's homes"), unless that rule is enforced by the game mode and the environment.

Is it possible for a faction to set up a home base that simply cannot be breached from the outside by other players (unless someone from the inside grants them access)?

Comment: There is a world of traps to be discovered, but there is a huge assymetry, and a month of defense preparations could easily be penetrated within hours.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Not reasonably

Nothing you can build in vanilla Minecraft is indestructible.

That said, Simply Sarc recently posted a video on his channel, where he shows off a way to actually make a base indestructible, using 60 Elder Guardians, which are synched up so that one of them uses his curse every second. That means thats any player in the vicinity can't *not* have Mining Fatigue III for more than a second at a time.

This doesn't make your base truly indestructible, but depending on the material you used for building it, it will make breaking into a base take an awfully long amount of time.

Of course, your team would also be unable to break things inside your base, but you could have a redstone-operated door which can only be opened from the inside.

In pure survival, your team would need to capture these guardians manually, which involves raiding at least 20 ocean monuments. It is also possible to synchronize the curse timers, although the video doesn't go into details, mostly because ot would be utterly ridiculous to even attempt this method of base protection.

Comment: Clever idea, but I would think the use of command blocks makes it somewhat unusable for the average player. Also, if you're going to use command blocks, you could probably apply the effect to only enemy players (using scoreboards and a redstone clock) without using the mobs at all. Although it would still be vulnerable to TNT cannons.

Comment: The command blocks used on the video are for convenience only. It is possible to do in pure vanilla by manually capturing 60 elder guardians, and aynchronization of the curse timrs is also doable according to the video. It's just utterly unreasonable.

Comment: When I asked the question, I thought the answer would be something involving the maximum build height, the bedrock, lava and possibly a few redstone contraptions. This caught me by surprise, but I like it a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Just make a complete bedrock cube. This is your base. Set your spawn point inside the cube. Make sure there is no entrance. Turn keep inventory on, and when ever you need to get home, just kill yourself. No one can get inside, except you, because their spawn point is not set in your base. They can only get inside through Creative mode. For extra security, make it small, short, and make the floor the bedrock at the bottom of the world. When miners dig down, they'll think your base is the bottom of the world! Or just use command blocks saying only ________ can open base.

Comment: People can still use ender pearls to get inside the base.

Comment: How are you supposed to accomplish this starting from a randomly generated survival world?

Answer (score 0):

Yes I think it's potentially possible but may require a lucky find in terms of bedrock placement or a lot of patience.  Plus you'll need a LOT of sticky pistons and a fair amount of redstone.  Basically the idea is that you tunnel down to bedrock and build up from there, then you place sticky pistons (pistons facing up) in a pyramid as your walls.  Set up an apparatus inside that constantly sends out ultra short redstone pulses that cause the piston to extend and contract.  place blast resistant blocks on the outside on top of the pistons (so that the pistons are constantly shaking the blocks) and make sure all the pulses are powered by the pulses.  This will make sure your blast resistant walls are constantly in motion (and thus un-minable) and no tnt will have any effect from the blast resistance.  The only tricky bit will be tucking the pistons effectively behind the bedrock so that none of them are exposed.  Fashion some sort of door on the top which grabs one of you pistons and pulls it down far enough for someone to enter and you've got it.  The door may only be activated from the inside so be very careful.  Also I can't imagine this is particularly server friendly, and I suspect it will be very loud.  If you don't care about any of this however, you should be able to make a 100% person proof base.  Enjoy.

Answer (score -1):

Here's a method you could try:

1. Create a wall of lava
2. Create a wall of obsidian
3. Create a wall of water with the water on the outside and inside
4. Cover both with obsidian

Here's a more visual example of the idea:

```
outside of base

————————  obsidian 
water
——————- 
lava
————————— obsidian


Inside of base
```

The players can destroy one wall of obsidian and the second, and if they do it will turn to cobblestone. Because they need a 2x1 hole, the cobblestone will regenerate when they break the second block.

This is not “unbreakable" but it is nearly impossible to get through.